# How to get intellij to pick up new environment variable value without machine restart?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

When I change the value of an environment variable (on Windows 7), intellij doesn't see that unless I restart the machine. Shutting down and reopening intellij doesn't help. I verified that I could see the new value of the environment variable in a new command prompt, but not in intellij (version 14).

Comment: Could you just set them as custom environment variables in your run configuration ?

Comment: Id like to be able to use the actual environment variables and not set anything again within intellij.

Comment: what OS are you using

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

Comment: ohh sorry you did say...

Comment: not to be patronising but youre not setting the environment variable in the command prompt window are you because thats not actually going to store it, it just sets it for the current command prompt session, which could be why you dont see it in intellij

Comment: No I am storing it by opening the environment variable window. Then I open a new command prompt window and am able to read it there. If you have intellij try it out.

Comment: I usually edit the idea.bat that comes with Ij installation. Can you try using that route and see if defining an env var in idea.bat helps? (Start by invoking idea.bat itself).